# Debugging mapreduce functions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, debugging, mapreduce

I am trying to debug the standard MapReduce examples of matlab to get a better understanding of the concept. There is also a Mathworks description how to do it (http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/debug-mapreduce-algorithms.html). But if I follow the instructions and set the breakpoint and then execute `MaxMapReduceExample;` the program won't stop. So I can't run the programm line by line. This Problem also arises in other algorithms. But when I write a script and put some breakpoints directly in this script, the execution would stop appropriately.

What kind of problem is this? And how can I fix it?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you post some more detailed reproduction steps for this problem?

If you follow the steps in the example then execution of MaxMapReduceExample should halt when it reaches the breakpoint you added.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Matlab cannot consider breakpoints when using a parallel pool. So for me it helped to uncheck the option "Automatically create a parallel pool" in the preferences of the Parallel Computing Toolbox and shutting down all active parallel pools using

```
p = gcp;
delete
```